# How do you allow only inputs from a list? (python vending machine)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to code a vending machine, that only accepts certain coins

> "It will allow you to input 1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, 50p and £1.00 but it will REJECT a £2.00 coin"

I have a list, with float values inside:

```
coins = ["0.01","0.02","0.05","0.10","0.20","0.50","1"]
```

These are the coins, that I am wanting the user to enter into

```
coin = float(input())
```

And after this I have

```
def balance():
     coin = float(input("Please enter your coins."))
     if coin not in coins:
            print("Incorrect coin amount! Please remember we don't accept 2 pound coins!")

     else:
        print("Correct coin amount. The coins have been added to your balance")
        fb = fb + coin
```

I couldn't get this to work, as it would just print "Incorrect coin amount! Please remember we don't accept 2 pound coins!".
After this, I tried this solution already on here: [Python Coding - Vending machine - How to get the user to only enter certain coins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091208/python-coding-vending-machine-how-to-get-the-user-to-only-enter-certain-coin/23091227#23091227)
I thought this meant I needed to change my float(input()) and everything float to int, so changing 0.01 (1p) to 1. But, when I did, I stil got

```
'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

When using it in this code

```
dict = {"KitKat":"80p", "Coca-Cola":"85p", "DairyMilk":"80p","Walkers Crisps":"90p"}
coins = ["1","2","5","10","20","50","100"]

def balance():
    inp = int(input("Please enter your coins. Please enter in pence, for example 1 pound = 100"))
    if any(int(coin) not in value for coin in inp.split()):
        print("Machine doesn't accept these coins")


else:
    print("Correct coin amount. The coins have been added to your balance")
    fb = fb + coin


def items():
    print (" 1. KitKat:" , dict['KitKat'])
    print (" 2. Coca-Cola:", dict['Coca-Cola'])
    print (" 3. Dairy Milk:", dict["DairyMilk"])
    print (" 4. Walkers Crisps:", dict["Walkers Crisps"])
snack = 1 # need a while loop, ignore
fb = 0.00
balance()
print("Your full balance is",fb)
```

Comment: It's called validation. Use a loop to check if an input is in a list.

Comment: If you are dealing with money you should use the decimal lib http://stackoverflow.com/a/32533307/2141635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend converting pounds to pence so you don't have to do float math, and just convert back any time you're displaying values. You could also use the `decimal` module for this, but let's not get too involved in that yet. Your ultimate problem seems to be that you're comparing different types of values, and `1 != "1"`. Let's sort that first.

```
coins = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]  # pence
coin_in = int(input("Enter amount (in pence): "))

if coin_in not in coins:
    # incorrect input, handle it
```

Comment: might as well use a set of coins

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, just didn't want to throw anything new at them while they're still trying to figure out what they've already been taught. A set `set([1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100])` (or `{1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100}`) would be the perfect data type for this, but I doubt that OP has learned about them yet

Comment: Never too early to learn about efficiency ;) I thinks set are an important thing to learn about they are often the difference between quadratic and linear runtime.

Comment: @AdamSmith Correct, I haven't learnt about sets yet, nor most of the stuff in this homework. So if I change coins = [] to coins ([]), would it be a better script? Thanks for the help, worked perfectly, gotta fix a couple errors that I've somehow generated, though :)

Comment: @user3670603 The syntax is `set([1, 2, 5, ...])`. Or you can use the literal notation which looks like a dictionary with no values, only keys `{1, 2, 5, ...}`. In fact, thinking of sets as dictionaries without values makes a TON of sense. Both are unordered, both have very fast (O(1)) lookups, and neither support duplicates (you can't do `{1, 1, 1, 1}` like you can do `[1, 1, 1, 1]`)